# error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'MicrosoftOfficeCore (>= 15.0.0)' for 'net5.0'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, nuget, nuget-package

In Terminal of Visual Studio Code, when I try to run:

```
dotnet add package MicrosoftOfficeCore --version 15.0.0
```

I get the following error on Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'MicrosoftOfficeCore (>= 15.0.0)' for 'net5.0'
error: Package 'MicrosoftOfficeCore' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project
```

Do anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

1. Try clearing the NuGet cache using `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`, and then try to add your package.
2. If that doesn't work, try deleting the `NuGet.config` file present inside `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` directory, and then restore it using `dotnet restore` command. Try adding your package after this.

The above solution works irrespective of whichever .NET version you're using.

Comment: 1. Same error
2. Works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks a lot, we had the second problem with a fresh install of dotnet sdk 5.0.400.

Comment: worked perfect, in my case `<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />`  was missing as a package source in the default nuget.config created by the installation.

Comment: I had problem #2 from a net6.0 install using official scripted installer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script.  same missing line as @baywet

Comment: Got the error when creating a new webapi after installing .NET 7.0. Deleting the NuGet.config and "dotnet restore" fixed it.

Comment: Step number 2 fixed it for us, too. First step had no effect on our machine.

Comment: Step #2 works, but `dotnet restore` may not work. In this case, simply re-run command you were trying to run. (e.g. dotnet install, dotnet add, etc.) Then, it will automatically add missing configuration as outlined by @baywet above.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that whether you're having **Nuget.config** file in your root folder or not.
If you don't have **Nuget.config** file, just create it and add the below code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- You can add additional sources as needed -->
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Now, re-run the **dotnet restore**. This will definitely solve the error of NU1100