# Nuget package for mysql .net5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am just trying to create a hello world using .NET core console application which can connect to MySQL database (running in a container).

When I am trying to use a Nuget package:

```
dotnet add package MySql.Data --version 8.0.26
```

It doesn't work for me and I am getting below error. I believe this should support .NET core 5, not sure how to check if this supported by .NET core and what version.
Can someone please help me understand what I am missing here?

```
PS C:\coding\c#\helloworld> cd .\sampleapp\
PS C:\coding\c#\helloworld\sampleapp> dotnet add package MySql.Data --version 8.0.26
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\manish\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2756.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'MySql.Data' into project 'C:\coding\c#\helloworld\sampleapp\sampleapp.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\coding\c#\helloworld\sampleapp\sampleapp.csproj...
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'MySql.Data (>= 8.0.26)' for 'net5.0'.
  Determining projects to restore...
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'MySQL.Data' into project 'C:\coding\c#\helloworld\sampleapp\sampleapp.csproj'.
error: There are no versions available for the package 'MySQL.Data'.
```

Comment: This does not answer your question directly but I recommend using `MySqlConnector` and ditch `MySQl.Data`. Couple reasons its out performs and is async all the way through!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting @rippo , let me give a try, is MySqlConnector, does the same works for mariadb as well?

Comment: Yes mate thats what I use it for!

Comment: MySql.Data 8.0.26 shows [on NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) that it supports .NET 5

Comment: I wonder if your NuGet sources aren't configured correctly, because `MySql.Data` does support `net5.0`. However, like @Rippo I would strongly recommend MySqlConnector instead.

Comment: Tried with MySqlConnector, but unfortunately got the same issue. not very sure if there is an issue with my setup.  `C:\coding\c#\helloworld\sampleapp>dotnet --version
5.0.302`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on this post

[error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'MicrosoftOfficeCore (>= 15.0.0)' for 'net5.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283730/error-nu1100-unable-to-resolve-microsoftofficecore-15-0-0-for-net5-0)

I needed to delete this directory to make it work

C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet