# Trouble running ASP.NET exercise, multiple NU1100 exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, package, sdk

I've been trying to learn .NET and am in the middle of the the learning path on the Microsoft learning site and it has be conduct an exercise from [this link](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/APL-2002-develop-aspnet-core-consumes-api/Instructions/Labs/01-interact-with-an-api.html). When I unzip and try and run it I get these errors:

```
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 7.0.9)' for 'net7.0'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory (>= 7.0.9)' for 'net7.0'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.5.0)' for 'net7.0'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations (>= 6.5.0)' for 'net7.0'.
```

I've run into a similar issue a number of times since net8.0 recently released and Microsoft has yet to update their courses to account for that, but any adjustments I try and make to this don't resolve the issue. Here's the full original FriutAPI.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="7.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've tried changing the target framework to net8.0, changing the versions of the package being targeted, I've even gone and downloaded net7.0 to no luck. Most of the exercises until now have had me generating and adjusting a new dotnet csproj so I'm not used to dealing with such errors and problems.

Any advice as to what is happening or how to resolve it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283730/error-nu1100-unable-to-resolve-microsoftofficecore-15-0-0-for-net5-0

Comment: @TimothyG. I had not! I could've sworn I had looked up and gone through a number of posts and missed that somehow.  It's now throwing a benign comment about missing XML comments but it's running! Should I delete this question since there's an answer elsewhere?

Comment: You should be able to self-close your post as a duplicate of that one, or delete it.