# How to write a minimal .NET C# app which will save a string to a Azure Blob?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am a Java developer, but I need to do the AZ-204 certificate and all questions are in C#. Now I like to see things "in action", so I asked ChatGTP to generate me a program to create a file in Azure Blob and he came up with this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>false</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>false</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Identity" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And now the c# file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace these values with your actual Azure Blob Storage information
        var blobStorageUrl = "https://somestorage.blob.core.windows.net/";
        var containerName = "somecontainer1";
        var blobName = "vm1example.txt"; // Name of the file in Blob Storage

        // Create a token credential using the system-assigned managed identity
        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

        // Create a BlobServiceClient using the token credential
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobStorageUrl), tokenCredential);

        // Get a reference to the container
        var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Create or get a reference to the blob
        var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        // Specify the content to write to the blob
        var content = "Hello, Azure Blob Storage!";

        // Convert the content to bytes
        var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

        // Create a stream from the content bytes
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(contentBytes))
        {
            // Upload the content to the blob
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("String written to Blob Storage successfully.");
    }
}
```

I tried to build this with:

dotnet build -o out

I installed SDK 8.0, but nothing I do will make this thing compile. The error for the exact thing above is:

> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Azure.Storage.Blobs (>= 12.10.0)' for 'net6.0'.
> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.Identity (>= 1.7.0)' for 'net6.0'.
> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref (= 6.0.25)' for 'net6.0'
> .
> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref (= 6.0.25)' for '
> net6.0'.
> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref (= 6.0.25)' for 'net6
> .0'.
> C:\programas\writeblobfile.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 (= 6.0.25)' for
> 'net6.0'.
> 0 Warning(s)
> 6 Error(s)

I know that there are Microsoft Samples for this, but they are huge, and include a huge number of includes from all over. Can't we just have a tiny project which does this?

thanks,

Comment: Have you installed the Azure.Storage.Blobs nuget package?

Comment: dotnet build won't auto download dependencies?

Anyway:

>dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs --version 12.10.0
  Determining projects to restore...
....
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Azure.Storage.Blobs (>= 12.10.0)' for 'net6.0'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.Identity (>= 1.7.0)' for 'net6.0'.
....

Comment: You have a compatibility issue between the Target project Net 6.0 (Core) and SDK 8.0.  See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/migrationGuides/V8_V12.md

Comment: google the error    or refer this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283730/error-nu1100-unable-to-resolve-microsoftofficecore-15-0-0-for-net5-0  ,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred due to a compatibility issue between the Target project Net 6.0 and SDK 8.0 and also you are using an older version of Azure identity.

According to the **[Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity)** you can use the latest version of azure identity     `<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.3" />`

In my environment, I have tried with latest package and version and it uploaded a text document with content.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Same code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var blobStorageUrl = "https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net";
        var containerName = "sample";
        var blobName = "vm1example.txt";
        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobStorageUrl), tokenCredential);
        var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
        var content = "Hello, Azure Blob Storage!";
        var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(contentBytes))
        {
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("String written to Blob Storage successfully.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"String written to Blob Storage successfully."
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Update:**

Even with SDK 8.0 I can upload the text file to Azure blob storage  Try to upgrade your Azure blob storage and Azure identity NuGet package.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: So you mean I should uninstall SDK8 and install SDK6? Or I can have both at the same time in the same machine?

I thought it is all backwards compatible or something...

Ideally I'd prefer to have a working code for SDK8, but I guess if it isn't possible I'll downgrade, just a pitty because SDK6 download page states it will be obsolete in November 2024 so that's a short shelf life.

Comment: Even with SDK 8.0 I can able to upload the text file to azure blob storage https://i.imgur.com/vCIuddN.png
Please, Try to upgrade your `Azure blob storage` and `azure identity` nuget package

Comment: ok, thanks, but I must be missing something obvious. My steps are: 1> Create a new Windows VM 2> Download .NET SDK v8.0 3> Try to compile the thing above with "dotnet build -o out". So I have absolutely nothing else installed or configured in this system. I tried to clear the locals with "dotnet nuget locals all --clear", tried "dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs --version 12.19.1" -> same NU110 error "Unable to resolve 'Azure.Storage.Blobs (>= 12.19.1)' for 'net8.0'". Right now I'm working in the 8.0 version you posted in the screenshot. Maybe something else needs to be downloaded?

Comment: Try with this `dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs --version 12.19.1 --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Single-handedly this command allowed me to build and run the project!